# How do I know what my IPP URI for my printer?

Tags: printing

I have connected a networked HP laserjet printer and need to add it as a print queue using lpadmin which takes a URI parameter. However, I have seen different formats for the URI like:

> ipp://1.2.3.4/ipp/print

or just simply:

> ipp://1.2.3.4

and many more. How do I know what URI my printer is expecting?

Comment: Does the printer has the functionality to print out his network status? Sometimes the printer prints this on a test page printout.

Comment: @mnille The printer just says it can use the ipp protocol and the web interface has the ability to turn it on and off, but doesn't say what kind of URI it is expecting.